# Using Server Side Paging with Kendo-React-ui

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I'm new on Kendo-React-UI 
I have a API with 2 required params (countSkip, pageSize) 
I have read this [discussed](https://www.telerik.com/forums/return-total-results-when-server-side-paging)  But the API in example has not the params like mine. 
What should I do?

Comment: The posted forum link is not related to Kendo React suite.

Answer (score 2):

The Grid's `GridPageChangeEvent` has a `page` object with two properties, `take` and `skip`.
The `take` is like your `pageSize`. And the `skip` is like the `countSkip`.

```
<Grid
   data={this.state.items}
   pageChange={(e)=> { this.CallYourAPI(e.page.skip, e.page.take);}} 
> 
... 
</Grid>
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/data-operations/paging/) about the paging.

Comment: The official documentation suggests that kendo wants all data to be retrieved to mid-tier, is that correct or am I misunderstanding the example?